# display ALL the information of a command with 'git anycommand -h'

Tags: git

I just found out a very useful option to use with the "git log" command: "-p". But if I write "git log -h" in windows git bash I don't get any information about the "-p" option, no way to discover it if I don't know it exists. Do you know what I can type to get all the information about the "log" command, and, in general, any command? Thank you.

Comment: I see a `-p` flag on the git log man page mentioned but I can't tell what it does. Are you referring to the paginate shorthand flag, `-p`?

Comment: no, I'm referring to the option that shows you the details of the modifications. I think "p" it's a shortcut for "patch"

Comment: `man git-log` gives you all you need.  `git log --help` should give you the man page also.

Comment: The `-h` option is conventionally not the full docs, just a very quick look.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out any of these

```sh
git help log
man git-log
```

Git commands are also readable online at `https://git-scm.com/docs/git-COMMAND`, [git log is here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for example. It's basically the same as `git help COMMAND` but some would find it easier to read.

Comment: man doesn't work on windows, but I will keep the "git help log", even if I don't find very readable the documentation associated with it. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer so as to also include where the online docs are, I think you'd find them more readable

Comment: Also, `git log --help` will access the man page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is in this line from the git log help page:

> The command takes options applicable to the git-rev-list[1] command to control what is shown and how, and options applicable to the git-diff[1] command to control how the changes each commit introduces are shown.

So, `git log` can also take the options passable to `git rev-list` and `git diff`. In this case, the `-p` flag is documented on the page for [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_options), which you can also get to with `git help diff`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer I was looking for. In fact, "log" and "diff" have common options. So you get all the info you need if you type "git diff -h", instead! There you go!

Comment: Yes but you were already _given_ that answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67186806/341994 The correct procedure is not to _repeat_ the answer that helped you, but to _accept_ it.